# safari glitch with z-index

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

I've discovered this glitch in safari and it is driving me nuts. Its a glitch, because if any of the browser events is fired (hover, click) element takes correct z-index.

The issue is with z-index and position:fixed element.

[image]
You can see it live [here](http://ambebi.weare.de.com/msoplio/129548-tragedia-everestze-chamotsolilma-zvavma-65-alpinisti-imskhverpla.html) scroll down so it gets activated and than slowly scroll up not triggering buttons.

I've discovered that using `transform: translatez(1);` helps but creates more serious bugs down the line.

any thoughts?

Comment: I'm getting the same result on Safari as Chrome, which I'm guessing is the desired result: not that screenshot you have there. If you've been using safari a lot to develop that site it may be to do with browser caching. Have you tried a [force refresh](http://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/)?

Comment: @jaunt I'm on mac safari, results may vary between OS X and windows.